# Jquery dialog freezing when Firebug is active

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

I have very simple jquery dialog like

```
$(".myDialog").dialog({
    close: function() { 
        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
    }
});
```

the code worked perfectly until i've updated to jquery 1.9.1 and firefox 19 + firebug 1.11.2.
Now it freezes firefox, but still works if i have firebug closed.

Unfortunately i couldn't find similar problems, and for now i have small workaround:

```
if (window.console && (window.console.firebug || window.console.exception)) {
    $(this).dialog('close').remove();
}
```

of course it's only partial solution, maybe someone has another options ?

UPD: seems it falls to infinite recursion only if bootstrap bootstrap-dropdown.js plugin included. 
i've posted the whole example here http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4938

Comment: Probably Firebug want you to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is `StackOverflow Exception` inside jquery (1.9.0 in my situation). This is more specific info:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^|\.)dialog9(\.|$)/: Stack overflow
```

So I'll look after solution in few hours and report as soon as possible.